# How to check for custom OpenID claim in an IAM role's trust policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-iam, auth0

I am authenticating users with auth0 to receive a id token containing the following claim

```
"http://myapp.com/scope": "write"
```

Using a Cognito identity pool with an OpenID authentication provider (namely, auth0), I am able to successfully get temporary credentials to access aws services. However, I want to restrict access to these services based on my custom claim above. I believe the proper way to do this is by editing the trust policy associated with my identity pool, but I am not sure how to add a condition to check for the above claim in my trust policy.

The current default trust policy is

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "us-east-2:078855cf-aa9b-400e-a762-dfcf27ec495c"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I ensure that only users with the auth0 **"write"** scope have access to write to my s3 service?

UPDATE:

I was able to pass the original id_token to aws by avoiding the cognito identity pool. However, auth0 forces my custom claims to be namespaced with `"http://mywebsite.com"`. This is a problem because IAM does not allow multiple colons in my condition. I need to add the condition

```
"ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
    "food-flick.auth0.com/:https://foodflick.com/scope": "write:rests"
 }
```

But IAM won't allow it and Auth0 forces me to namespace my claims. What can I do? I could store my scopes in a standard claim, but that would be misleading. Can I pass my access token instead of my id_token to IAM? If so, how would I change the trust policy to check for the appropriate aud value when given an array of values?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: no I did not. I went with firebase, using signInWithCustomToken.

my auth0 server returns a firebase token in its idToken

Comment: Any solution was found for this?

Answer (score 0):

Federated claims are not propagated into the AWS session and are not accessible in the trust policy.  Likely the path forward is to use [RoleMappings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_RoleMapping.html) to map your custom claim to a particular role.  Unfortunately at this time, I believe there is an outstanding issue preventing rolemapping from working with OIDC.  I will update this post if the issue is resolved.

Comment: does this mean I cannot use cognito? where would I find rolemappings from the cognito console? would I be able to achieve my use case through the steps at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc_manual.html?

Comment: Is this still an issue 9 months later?

Comment: We just fixed support for OIDC and rolemappings, can you try now?

Comment: Any solution for this? Can we now use RoleMappings to map custom claims to a role? I'm not using cognito and I'm using a custom Provider.